# How to get updated table names in sql server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Currently I'm getting all table names in the db and adding to `List<string> saka` and `listbox1` with:

```
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        fare = bag.GetSchema("Tables");            
        foreach (DataRow zil in fare.Rows)
        {
           saka.Add(zil["table_name"].ToString());
           listBox1.Items.Add(zil["table_name"].ToString());

        }
```

Is it possible to get only updated table names? I mean a column "stts" can be added with 3 value `(0,1,2) 0=unread,1=read;2=read` and changed, so can we get tables which have "0" value in its "stts" column? or is there another way to do this?

An additional question (optional :) ): I have `fill()` under the `listBox1_DoubleClick` event. Likewise can we get it fill the dgv with only specific table rows which has "1" value in that "stts" column?

```
        private void fill()

        sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + saka[listboxselectedindex], conn);
        dataset = new DataSet();
        sqlAdapter.Fill(dataset, saka[listboxselectedindex]);
        datagridview1.DataSource = null;
        datagridview1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[saka[listboxselectedindex]];
```

Update: (is doing like this efficient?)

```
               foreach (DataRow zil in fare.Rows)
        {
            saka.Add(zil["table_name"].ToString());
          //  listBox1.Items.Add(zil["table_name"].ToString());                
        }            
        for (int n = 0;n  < saka.count; n++)
        {                
                sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from " + saka[n] + " where durum = '4'", conn);
                DataSet astana = new DataSet();                    
                sqlAdapter.Fill(astana, saka[n]);
                if (astana.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(saka[n]);
                }
                astana = null;          


        }
```

Comment: Since a table might have lots of rows - which of the rows of that table must have the value `stts = 0` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + saka[listboxselectedindex]+" where stts=@sttsValue", conn);
sqlAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sttsValue",1);
            dataset = new DataSet();
            sqlAdapter.Fill(dataset, saka[listboxselectedindex]);
            datagridview1.DataSource = null;
            datagridview1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[saka[listboxselectedindex]];
```

Comment: it worked as I wanted while getting only updated rows to dtg but I cant get updated tables. now I check all table names which column stts has value that wanted(can you check my update on the quest) is this efficient?

Answer (score 0):

is the SqlDataAdapter a need for your project?
if not, it might be easier to use Entity Framework with a little to no work to make those changes to your project

this should be the solution for both:

```
dataset.Tables[saka[listboxselectedindex]].AsEnumerable().Where(row => row["ColumnName"] == 1).ToList();
```

note that "ColumnName should be changed to the name of the Column to make it work